# Linux pipe: Bad file descriptor in functions read and write

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm learning about pipes in C and I have a problem with my code:

My program creates a child process and a pipe between parent process and child process. I'm trying to send a simple string from parent to child through pipe. But for some reason I get an error messages for functions **read** and **write**:

```
"read error: Bad file descriptor"
"write error: bad file descriptor"
```

I have no idea, where the problem is, I've just started learning about pipes in C.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int err( const char* what )//function that writes errors
{
    perror( what );
    exit( -1 );
}

int main()
{
    int fdes[2]; //File descriptors for pipe
    pid_t pid;
    char string[20] = "Hello World\n";//string that I want to send to childs process

    int p = pipe( fdes ); //Creating pipe
    if( p < 0 )
        err( "pipe error\n");

    pid = fork(); //Creating process
    if( pid < 0 )
        err( "fork error\n" );

    if( pid == 0 ) //child
    {
        p = close( fdes[0] ); //Closing unused "write" end of pipe for child
        if( p < 0 )
            err( "close error\n" );

        char str[20]; //I save the message from parent in this string
        int p;
        p = read( fdes[1], str, strlen(str) );// Trying to receive the message and save it in str[]
        if( p < 0 )
            err( "read error\n" );

        printf( "Child received: %s\n", str );
    }
    else //parent
    {
        p = close( fdes[1] ); //Closing unused "read" end of pipe for parent
        if( p<0 )
            err( "close error\n");

        p = write( fdes[0], string, strlen( string ) ); //Trying to send the message to child process
        if( p < 0 )
            err( "write error\n" );

        printf( "Parent sent: %s\n", string );
        
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `p = read( fdes[1], str, strlen(str) );` you are calling strlen() on an uninitialised char array. Use `p = read( fdes[1], str, sizeof str );` here, or just `20`

Answer (score 4):

You are reading from and writing to the wrong file descriptors. From the [pipe man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe):

> pipefd[0] refers to the read end of the pipe. pipefd[1] refers to the
>   write end of the pipe.

Answer (score 1):

`read(2)` returns `EBADF` if *"`fd` is not a valid file descriptor or **is not open for reading***"; likewise for `write(2)` you get `EBADF` if the descriptor is not open for writing.

---

The  function `int pipe2(int pipefd[2], int flags);` returns 2 file descriptors so that

> - `pipefd[0]` refers to the read end of the pipe.
> - `pipefd[1]` refers to the write end of the pipe.

Think about the file descriptors in the array corresponding to `STDIN_FILENO` and `STDOUT_FILENO`. You'd `read` from **0** (like `STDIN_FILENO`), and `write` to **1** (like `STDOUT_FILENO`).

Comment: But if I change the flags for **stdin** and **stdout** will I be able to use **printf** and other **<stdio.h>** functions normally? Will it give me the output from printf on the screen?

Comment: Also if I use a **dup2** function to change my file descriptors will I get the same results as above?